# load data to dropdown in java?

Tags: java

I have some problem where I am getting my data from my API call when I print in the console. I am getting **{id: 0000, label: TEST}** as my results. What I need to do is populate the `label` to show in my dropdown as a value where the user can select from. Is there a way with my code below? thanks for the help.

Here is my code:

> Using Jersey Library:

```
  public List<JobSearchItem> getjobSearchList() {

    Client restClient = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    Response response = restClient.target("https://api.myjson.com/bins/7xq2x").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
    return response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<JobSearchItem>>() {});


}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return new StringBuilder().append("[value=").append(value).append(", label=").append(label).append("]")
            .toString();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use any of the well known libraries/frameworks for retrieving and reading JSON contents from an api call? For example [jersey](https://jersey.github.io/)

Comment: can you please show me a working example to my code above by using jersey to see how it works? I tried using gson but failed. if you can show me how so I can learn from other developers.

Comment: Your updated code won't work unless you rename the fields `label` and `value` into `name` and `abbreviation` and write their getters/setters OR you could write your own custom deserialiser, but this is more complicated.

Comment: and also, why are you returning `null` in your `getjobSearchList()` method?

Comment: I am using a different url that is private (sorry about that), that it returns label and value. and I don't know that is why I need some help and guidance.

Comment: Ah okay then, but you need to know that names have to match or you need to handle it in your custom deserialiser.

Comment: sounds good. So, with the below code of yours.. can you show me a way to use from my code above?

Comment: I think this is best of what I can do to show you how to use Jersey to retrieve the list. Otherwise, I need to be sitting next to you and have the exact code that you have to be able to help. This should be sufficient enough for you to figure it out how to incorporate it in your code.

Comment: can you show me with `gson` library?

Comment: If you know how to use gson, then just read the entity as a string `response.readEntity(String.class)` and then process the returned string using gson. It's as easy as that.

Comment: You modified the original question, and now my answer doesn't make sense. This is not how you are supposed to use Stackoverflow. If you want two questions answered, you post two questions. And once you have an answer to your question, you hit the accept button on the answer that suits your question best.

Comment: Accepting your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes thanks, but it doesn't quite answer your question (I think). What is your current question, what's the problem you are facing. For these cases, it's nice to create a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: So, I created new question. with the attempt of using gson. Can you see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57332602/how-to-parse-json-correctly-with-gson-in-java

Comment: Can't find the question: Page not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, it is very easy if you use a library or framework that does the heavy lifting for you. Here's a very simple example of retrieving the list using [Jersey](https://jersey.github.io/).

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class ListExtractor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client restClient = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        Response response = restClient.target("https://api.myjson.com/bins/7xq2x").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
        List<Item> items = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<Item>>() {});
        items.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    static class Item {
        private String name;
        private String abbreviation;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getAbbreviation() {
            return abbreviation;
        }

        public void setAbbreviation(String abbreviation) {
            this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return new StringBuilder().append("[name=").append(name).append(", abbreviation=").append(abbreviation).append("]")
                    .toString();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

I just modified the code a bit, so that it returns a list of items.

**Warning**: this is not production ready code. I haven't added any exception handling or logging, so that it remains short and conveys its purpose in a clear way.

You need to familiarise yourself with JSON serialisers/deserialisers, in order to understand what's going in the above example.

#### Explanation

If you look at the response from the link (https://api.myjson.com/bins/7xq2x), you see that it returns a JSON array, where each element of the array is: 
`{"name":"Alberta","abbreviation":"AB"}`. The JSON deserialiser provided by Jersey can convert (deserialise) this JSON object into a Java object if you have a class that has two fields named `name` and `abbreviation` (and their corresponding getters and setters).

This line of code

```
response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<Item>>() {});
```

will work out of the box because we have provided the `Item` class with fields named just like the keys in the JSON object above:

```
class Item {
        private String name;
        private String abbreviation;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getAbbreviation() {
            return abbreviation;
        }

        public void setAbbreviation(String abbreviation) {
            this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return new StringBuilder().append("[name=").append(name).append(", abbreviation=").append(abbreviation).append("]")
                    .toString();
        }
    }
```

Here's the modified example:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class ListExtractor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Item> items = getItems();
        items.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    static List<Item> getItems() {
        Client restClient = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        Response response = restClient.target("https://api.myjson.com/bins/7xq2x").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
        return response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<Item>>() {});   
    }


    static class Item {
        private String name;
        private String abbreviation;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getAbbreviation() {
            return abbreviation;
        }

        public void setAbbreviation(String abbreviation) {
            this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return new StringBuilder().append("[name=").append(name).append(", abbreviation=").append(abbreviation).append("]")
                    .toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Jersey dependencies (Gradle):

```
implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.25.1'
implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.25.1'
implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:2.25.1'
```

Comment: am I going to implement it in my `getjobSearchList` method - the code above?

Comment: and the code above it will get my data showing inside my dropdown, right?

Comment: can you please show me with my code above, i tried your answer it did not quite work?

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't not quite work"? What was the issue? Did you download all the dependencies needed by Jersey? You can user Gradle or Maven for dependency management.

Comment: thanks. But, can please not use the `Item` object. I am using `JobSearchItem` instead. can you please show like my code above?

Comment: and the dependency is `<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>` `<artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>` and `<version>2.29</version>`, right?

Comment: You need JAXB and JACKON. I updated the answer with all the dependencies needed.

Comment: so, the code above wont populate my data to load inside dropdown?

Comment: You can just rename it to `JobSearchItem` the name of the class doesn't matter, its field names (more precisely getters and setters) matter.

Comment: Your code will return `null` because you are doing `return null` - change this to `return items`.

Comment: so, in my `toString` (updated question) I get .append(value) and label, says `Cannot resolve symbol.

Comment: The it's a compilation issue. I think your IDE will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: it just says cannot find symbol.

Comment: The code above doesn't create or load any dropdown, it only returns a list which can be used as a model for a GUI dropdown.